# Regular expression to validate number greater than 0 and less than 1999

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a Regular expression to validate number greater than 0 and less than 1999.

I tried the below code but it require LiveValidation and lot of code.

```
var f8 = new LiveValidation('f8');
f8.add( Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 1999} );
```

Thanks

Comment: What is 'LiveValidation'? And I'm pretty sure you don't need a regex for this. A simple `if` will do.

Comment: +1 for parsing and checking value with `if` instead of going for regexp here.

Comment: Yes, why does it need to be a regexp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
^[0-1]?[0-9]{0,3}$
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1[0-8][0-9]{2}|19[0-8][0-9]|199[0-8])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just think how much time you are wasting just by looking for an answer to **compare a number with regular expression**. But I think as a programmer you know that `><` symbols are in every language to compare numbers. I recommend you use those.

```
function is_valid(strNum){
    var num = parseInt(strNum);
    return (num>0 && num<1999);
}
```

This code will do what you need and it'll not even waste time

Answer (score 1):

Check out this pattern:

```
^([0-9]{0,3}|1\d[0-8][9]|1\d{2}[0-8])$
```

It will allow values between 1 and 1998, inclusive.

Comment: @StephenConnolly, thank you for pointing out. I have updated pattern

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this with regex but try:

```
/^(?![2-9].{3})\d{1,4}$/
```

Again, this in *unnecesary*, but you get the idea.